# How to filter results in mongoose based on multiple conditions in populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of users to be displayed. I have 2 filters

1) Areas

2) Categories

I get proper filtered results when I apply only 1 filter i.e filter users based on selected categories or filter users based on areas.

Now I need to filter users based on both Categories and Areas selection. 
How should I approach to get the desired result?

Below is my working code to filter users based on selected categories:

```
    User.find().populate('city').populate( {path: 'categories', match: { name: { $in: filterCatArray }}} ).populate('area').exec(function (err, users) {

         users = users.filter(function(user) {
                return user.categories; // return only filtered users 
           });

         data = {fulldata:users}; 
         res.render('home',{data:data});

    });
```

**User schema:**

```
      var userSchema = new Schema({
      city: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City',required: true},
      area: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Area', required: true},
      categories: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true}],
      status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date
    });
```

**Area Schema**

```
    var areaSchema = new Schema({
      city: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City'},
      name: { type: String, required: true},
      status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date
    });
```

**Category Schema**

```
    var catSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true},
      status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date
    });
```

**City Schema**

```
    var citySchema = new Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true},
      status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date
    });
```

Comment: Would that not just simply be `users = users.filter( u => u.categories.length > 0 )` Given if the condition on the populate did not match then the resulting array would be empty, so exclude those users. Unless there is some other detail not explained in your question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm new to Mongoose, can you let me know what exactly is u in 'users = users.filter( u => u.categories.length > 0 )'

Comment: If you are not sure then edit your question to show the current output you get and what needs to change. Then we can answer properly.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Please add your schema's for the models being used here. That's "User", "Area" and "Categories" at least, and whatever `'city'` relates to as well. Then include enough sample documents from each collection to at least make a single valid result for the user, with the joined categories and other joined data. We solve problems by examples here, and not words. If you want someone to show you the correct query, then you need to supply them with the necessary data to produce the result.

Comment: @NeilLunn added my schemas.

Comment: And the "data". We need the data. Take the time to read the comments please.

Comment: You most likely need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to do your populating and filtering.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), but I recently started using it. I think `populate` is great for simple cases, but when you want to start doing complex stuff such as filtering results based off other collections, you need to use aggregation.

This is untested but it would look roughly like this:

```
UserSchema.aggregate([
    // 1 join city collection
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'citys',
            localField: 'city',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'city'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$city'
    },
    // 2 join area collection
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'areas',
            localField: 'area',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'area'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$area'
    },
    // 3 join categories collection
    {
        $unwind: '$categories'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'categories',
            localField: 'categories',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'category'
        }
    },
    // 4 filter results that only have specified categories
    {
        $match: { 
            'category.name': { $in: filterCatArray },
            'area.name': 'something' // just an example
        }
    },
    // 5 group results by user
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            city: { $first: '$city' },
            area: { $first: '$area' },
            categories: { $push: '$category' },
            status: { $first: '$status' },
            created_at: { $first: '$created_at' },
            updated_at: { $first: '$updated_at' },
        }
    }
], function (err, users) {

});
```

If there is a problem, comment each stage of the pipeline starting from the bottom to see what is happening.

For more information, read the following links:

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)
- [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)